# insert_id in Kohana 3

Tags: kohana, lastinsertid, insert-id

I'm using Kohana 3 framework with Mysql stored procedures. How can I get id of the last inserted record?
Here's the code:

```
class Model_MyModel extends Kohana_Model
{
    public function insertNew($param1, $param2)
    {
        $result = $this->_db->query(Database::INSERT, 'CALL insertNew('.$param1.', '.$param2.', false)';
        return $result;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Documentation says, the query() method returns an array with the last insert id and affected rows number, when executing an insert query. When I call: print_r($result)
I'm getting:
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
The insert_id key is 0, though I'm having many records in the db.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The reason your not getting the insert_id is because you using a procedure, have you ever tried to do the SQL right in the Database::INSERT?

Comment: It works when building sql in the script, thanks. However, is ot any way to call a procedure here, or it's absolutely impossible?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use SQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after inserting using a procedure:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as last_insert_id FROM table_name
```

( in your procedure just define this query in the end ).

The problem in this case is that Kohana automatically returns mysql_insert_id and mysql_affected_rows as result for Database::INSERT, so you'll need to call the procedure as a SELECT query and fetch it (Database::SELECT).