# How to call procedure in kohana 3.1

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, producer

Kohana is a php framework.
this is the documention .
how to call procedure in this framework.
i have searched and questions about this question.
like :
[insert_id in Kohana 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250621/insert-id-in-kohana-3)

this is my code :

```
$conn = Database::instance();       
$queryStr = "call sp_createUser('$nick_name','$email','$password','127.0.0.1')";
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, $queryStr);
$query->execute($conn);
```

but there's some exception..

```
Database_Exception [ 1312 ]: PROCEDURE sp_createUser can't return a result set in the given context [ call sp_createUser('1','1','1','127.0.0.1') ]
```

it seems that something wrong with the db connection..

how can i fix it ...ask some help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$query->compile(Database::instance);` before querying to inspect your query string and find it's bugs.

Also give us your PROCEDURE body. It semms like PROCEDURE returns data in incompatible format to Kohana.

Is your `$query->compile(Database::instance);` return string executes in mysql directly?

Comment: call sp_createUser('1','1','1','127.0.0.1') ,it can execute successfully in db .so nothing wrong with the query string.

Comment: What module do you use in PHP to work with MySQL? mod_mysql or mod_mysqli? Working with stored procedures requires mod_mysqli.

Comment: mod_mysql ,here's the framework documention:http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder

Comment: i think i find out the problem . i try to  create a random id for each user in the procedure , then i use "select account_id" return the account directly.i comment this ,the exception is gone.

Answer (score -2):

try replacing call with SELECT...

```
$queryStr = "SELECT sp_createUser('$nick_name','$email','$password','127.0.0.1')";
```

Comment: A procedure is invoked using a CALL statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/call.html)