# Kohana 3.2 and MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, kohana

I have a simple stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE `status_recalculate`(IN aid INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE actions INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE rid INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE actions_done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE status_done INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT request_id INTO rid FROM mtset_dev.actions a WHERE a.id=aid;
SELECT count(*) INTO actions FROM mtset_dev.actions a WHERE a.request_id=rid;

SELECT count(*) INTO actions_done FROM mtset_dev.actions a WHERE a.request_id=rid AND a.action_status=1;
SELECT CEIL(actions_done/actions*100) INTO status_done;

#UPDATE requests SET `status` = status_done WHERE id=rid;

SELECT rid, status_done;
END
```

And I want to call it from Kohana 3.2 via AJAX. In model there are code:

```
$query = "call status_recalculate($aid);";
DB::query(Database::SELECT, $query)->execute();
```

And there is no successful AJAX response. What am I doing wrong? How can I get result (or, perhaps, error)? Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169472/how-to-call-procedure-in-kohana-3-1) didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have solved it. All simple: mysql privilege to execute.

Comment: Surprised it wasn't throwing an error with a permissions message.

Comment: That was an AJAX call, and I haven't catch that error

Comment: Чтож, Вы, Павел, недосмотрели ))) Ответьте на свой вопрос самостоятельно чтобы его закрыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. All simple: mysql privilege to execute.